# how to disable encryption on SQL server 2014 connection that SSL is enforced by windows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, encryption

In windows 10 , Test connection with a udl file is successful. however, if "Use Encryption for data" was changed the to true. UDL Use Encryption the connection fail with error message:

"[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security Error.

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security Error.

The same message is presented when a simple Delphi app That I wrote to connect the SQL Server. This is the only computer it is happening in. Where to disable the OS rule that require apps to use encrypted connection?

Update:

using the management studio with this configuration will yeild error message:
[image]

however [image]
trust server certificate will connect to the server.

i have checked and the server does not have force connection. no certificates are installed.

Answer (score 3):

try to review wheter the encryption is forced or not:

in sql server configuration manager

- Expand SQL Server Network Configuration and right-click on Protocols
  for , then click Properties.
- On the Certificate tab, unselect certificate.
- Select No in the ForceEncryption box, then click OK.

To apply the configuration you have to restart sql server.

[image: certificate]

[image: force encryption]

Comment: i reinstalled the os on the client. and the server stay the same. it worked. it was an windos 10 configuration/error

Answer (score 0):

Not a fan of Windows, and just needed to get the database out from a backup file. Did not want to worry about SSL certificates etc. If you are not doing on this production, there is an easy way around it. Simply:

1. From the screen below, simply click on "Options >>"

[image]

2. Simply unselect "encrypt connection" and select "trust server certificate"

[image]

That worked for me! But this should not be used in production!